# Java iterator.hasNext() is always true

Tags: java, while-loop, iterator

I have a little problem with the code as seen below. The `iterator().hasNext()` will never turn into false because the `next()` function always returns the same element. It ends in an **infinite loop**.

I would like to set the attribute UserLock in every element in the collection (returned from  `GetElements()`).
If the type of the element is "Package", I will lock all elements under the package with a recursive call of the lockAllElements function.

```
private void lockAllElements(String internalGUID) {
    Element tempElem = null;

    while((repo.GetPackageByGuid(internalGUID).GetElements().iterator().hasNext()) == true) {
        tempElem = repo.GetPackageByGuid(internalGUID).GetElements().iterator().next();

        if(tempElem.GetType().equals("Package")) {                
            this.lockAllElements(tempElem.GetElementGUID());
        }

        tempElem.ApplyUserLock(); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It is always true because you get a new `Iterator` instance in each iteration of your loop. You should get a single `Iterator` instance and use that instance throughout the loop.

Change

```
while((repo.GetPackageByGuid(internalGUID).GetElements().iterator().hasNext()) == true) {
    tempElem = repo.GetPackageByGuid(internalGUID).GetElements().iterator().next();
    ...
```

to

```
Iterator<Element> iter = repo.GetPackageByGuid(internalGUID).GetElements().iterator();
while(iter.hasNext()) {
    tempElem = iter.next();
    ...
```

Answer (score 3):

Following on from @Eran's answer... I sometimes prefer a `for` loop:

```
for (Iterator<Element> iter = repo.GetPackageByGuid(internalGUID).GetElements().iterator(); iter.hasNext(); ) {
    tempElem = iter.next();
}
```

Comment: Clearly you can't make the mistake like this