# Java Iterator.hasNext() always true

Tags: java, object, hashmap, iterator, infinite-loop

I've already checked other questions [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32472568/java-iterator-hasnext-is-always-true) but it doesn't seem that I always create a new iterator which checks always the same object.

This is the code

```
        Iterator<Map.Entry<Node, Float>> it = graph.nodeNeighboursIterator(e); 
        System.out.println("extracted node "+ e.getLabel() + " number of neighbours "+ e.sizeNeighbours());
        while(it.hasNext()) {
            System.out.print(i + " " + e.getLabel() + " " + it +"-");
            i++;
        }
```

the method `graph.nodeNeighboursIterator` does this

```
public Iterator<Map.Entry<Node, Float>> nodeNeighboursIterator(Node n) {
    return this.graph_weighted.get(n).entrySet().iterator();
}
```

the `System.out.println("extracted node "+ e.getLabel() + " number of neighbours "+ e.sizeNeighbours());` prints the right number of neighbours but still the loop doesn't end his cycle, what do you think about it?

Comment: Are you calling `it.next()` inside the loop?

Comment: at the moment no for this test, but i should use it when i understand why the code doesn't work, right now in do stuff there is only a print and an int iterator to count

Comment: If you are not advancing the iterator (by calling it.next()) the loop will never end.

Comment: i thought that hasNext iterates the loop like next

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`it.hasNext()` checks if there is more data to be returned. This does *not* consume the data (in other words, does not iterate over the data). This operation is *idempotent*.

This is the reason why your loop never ends.

You need to actually consume the data by calling `it.next()`. `it.hasNext()` returns false if there are no more elements to return.

Answer (score 1):

You need revise your code to like below

```
while(it.hasNext()) {
    it.next();
}
```